# Trying to Create Custom Tooltip for LiveCharts WPF - Tooltip Doesn't Display Data

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, livecharts

All, I am having a lot of problems with displaying a custom tooltip for my LiveCharts control Here is my code and what I have tried.

Chart C# Code:

```
public partial class Chart : UserControl
{

    public ChartData chartData { get; set; }
   
    public Chart()
    {
        chartData = new ChartData();
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += Control_Loaded;
    }

    private void Control_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // build here
        DataContext = this;
        chartData.Formatter = value => value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        
    }
}
```

Chart XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LandlordTenantDatabaseWPF.Chart"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LandlordTenantDatabaseWPF"
         xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Chart}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding chartData.Title}" Foreground="#FF4B52E4" FontSize="36" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    
        <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="chart" Grid.Row="1" Series="{Binding chartData.SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Right" >            
            
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis Title="Month" Labels="{Binding chartData.Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Payments" LabelFormatter="{Binding chartData.Formatter}"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
            <local:CustomersTooltip/>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>            
</Grid>
```

ToolTip C# Code:

```
public partial class CustomersTooltip : IChartTooltip
{
    private TooltipData _data;
    public CustomersTooltip()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //LiveCharts will inject the tooltip data in the Data property
        //your job is only to display this data as required
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public TooltipData Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }
    public TooltipSelectionMode? SelectionMode { get; set; }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ToolTip XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LandlordTenantDatabaseWPF.CustomersTooltip"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LandlordTenantDatabaseWPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" 
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:CustomersTooltip}"
         Background="#E4555555" Padding="20 10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#555555">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Points}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpf:DataPointViewModel}">
            <Grid Margin="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Title"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LastName"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Phone"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="PurchasedItems"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Stroke="{Binding Series.Stroke}" Fill="{Binding Series.Fill}"
                           Height="15" Width="15"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Instance.(local:CustomerVm.Name)}" 
                           Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Instance.(local:CustomerVm.LastName)}" 
                           Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Instance.(local:CustomerVm.Phone), 
                                                    StringFormat=Phone: {0}}" 
                           Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Instance.(local:CustomerVm.PurchasedItems), 
                                                            StringFormat=Purchased Items: {0:N}}" 
                           Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

ChartData Class:

```
public class ChartData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SeriesCollection seriesCollection;

    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection
    {
        get { return seriesCollection; }

        set
        {
            if (seriesCollection != value)
            {
                seriesCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("seriesCollection");
            }
        }
    }

    private string[] labels;
    public string[] Labels
    {
        get { return labels; }
        set
        {
            if(labels != value)
            {
                labels = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("labels");
            }
        }
    }

    private string title;
    public string Title 
    { 
        get { return title; } 
        set
        {
            if(title != value)
            {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("title");
            }
        }
    }

    private Func<double, string> formatter;
    public Func<double, string> Formatter 
    { 
        get { return formatter; }
        set
        {
            if(formatter != value)
            {
                formatter = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("formatter");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the Window Containing the Chart:

```
private void AddNewSeries(List<double> lstPayments, string sSeriesName, SolidColorBrush colorBrush)
    {
        if (m_SeriesCollection == null)
        {
            m_SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
            { new ColumnSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double>(lstPayments),
                    Title = sSeriesName,
                    Fill = colorBrush                        
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            m_SeriesCollection.Add(
                new ColumnSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double>(lstPayments),
                    Title = sSeriesName,
                    Fill = colorBrush
                }
            );
        }
    }
private void UpdateChartsBasedOnDates(Chart chart, string sChartTitle)
    {    //Pass data to the chart       
        chart.chartData.SeriesCollection = m_SeriesCollection;
        chart.chartData.Labels = GetFormattedDates(m_lstCombinedDates);
        chart.chartData.Title = sChartTitle;            
    }
```

This all works perfectly when I just allow the default tooltip to be displayed on the chart. I am hung up on the fact that the chart data is supplied by a SeriesCollection, but the custom ToolTip, in the example on the LiveCharts website https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Tooltips%20and%20Legends doesn't use the SeriesCollection. Some of the charts displayed by my custom chart control have more than 1 series. I tried binding the Tooltip control to the SeriesCollection to get the data values, but that didn't work. Granted I may have done it incorrectly. Obviously the ToolTip XAML I am showing here is from the example code on the LiveCharts website, but I don't know where to go from here.

Is it possible to use make the tooltip use the series collection? What would be the best way for me to either use the Series Collection, or the ChartData class, or can I use

```
public TooltipData Data
{
    get { return _data; }
    set
    {
        _data = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Data");
    }
}
```

from the ToolTip C# code to display the data in the ToolTip?

I'm so confused.

Edit: I forgot to mention what my goal is. I want to display a tooltip that says

```
string.Format("{0} Payment: ${1}", SeriesName, PaymentAmount);
```

This would display Rent Payment: $1000. or MortgagePayment: $1000.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being a deep LiveCharts Tooltip Wiz I did manage to get a version going that worked for me. My chart is also using a `SeriesCollection`, so maybe this can be helpful for you.

This is how I integrated it into my chart:

```
CartesianChart cartesianChart = ...;
_cartesianChart.DataTooltip = new CustomTooltip
{
    SelectionMode = TooltipSelectionMode.OnlySender
};
```

This is my `CustomToolTip` class (I believe this is pretty much straight out of the documentation somewhere):

```
public partial class CustomTooltip : UserControl, IChartTooltip
{
    private TooltipData _data;

    public CustomTooltip()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //LiveCharts will inject the tooltip data in the Data property
        //your job is only to display this data as required

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public TooltipData Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }

    public TooltipSelectionMode? SelectionMode { get; set; }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public partial class CustomTooltip : UserControl, IChartTooltip, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _contentLoaded;

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        if (_contentLoaded)
            return;

        System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri(
            "/Plotting/CustomTooltipDesign.xaml",
            System.UriKind.Relative
        );
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

        _contentLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Then I built a XAML component, just like you. First super simple:

```
public partial class CustomTooltipDesign : UserControl
{
    public CustomTooltipDesign()
    {
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Then I had a little more effort to build the actual tooltip:

```
<UserControl x:Class="expomrf4utility.CustomTooltipDesign"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:expomrf4utility="clr-namespace:ExpoMRF4Utility" 
         xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance expomrf4utility:CustomTooltip}"
         x:Name="Control" d:DesignWidth="1" d:DesignHeight="1">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground}"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <wpf:SharedConverter x:Key="SharedConverter"/>
    <wpf:SharedVisibilityConverter x:Key="SharedVisibilityConverter"/>
    <wpf:ChartPointLabelConverter x:Key="ChartPointLabelConverter"/>
    <wpf:ParticipationVisibilityConverter x:Key="ParticipationVisibilityConverter"/>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Bvc"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedPoints" Source="{Binding Data.Points}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedPoints}}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                        <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle>
                        </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpf:DataPointViewModel}">
                                <Grid Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Title"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Label"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Label"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Series.Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Y, StringFormat='Value: {0} V/m'}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding ChartPoint, Converter={StaticResource ChartPointLabelConverter}, StringFormat='Datetime: {0}'}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

Note how I had to create bindings for the different properties that I wanted to display. To that end I slightly cheated when creating the data sets themselves. I used `GLineSeries` but I have a feeling it should work with other series as well:

```
int bandIndex = ...;
GearedValues<double> gearedValues = (some double[] data).AsGearedValues();
series.Add(new GLineSeries
{
    Values = gearedValues,
    LabelPoint = chartPoint => loggerData.Labels[(int)chartPoint.X].ToString(),
    Tag = bandIndex,
    Title = bandIndex.ToString()
});
```

Note that I `chartPoint.X` is the (zero-based) index of the the specific point (in X) - whereas `chartPoint.Y` is the Y-value of the point (also used in the XAML). Using this index I can look up in my list of names `loggerData.Labels` and return the timestamp associated with this index.

Comment: Thank you. I have since moved on from this project, but I will keep this in mind if I need to work with charts in the future. I'm glad you got it working.